# Where is the software / hardware boundary in modern computer systems?

Tags: hdl, computer-architecture

Computers are pogrammed in (and controlled by) software. That software is often run by other software (e.g. Java compiled into bytecode, run by a Java VM coded in machine instructions), which is in turn run by yet deeper software (CPU microcode, implementing the machine instructions). The hardware that runs the microcode might not be 'code' itself, but it can be 'created' from VHDL code. Where does this end, where does the 'real' hardware start? Obviously it can't be code all the way down to the atoms that make up the transistors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand the question. I had this very same question once. My code runs inside the CPU, but what does it run on? Answer: 'microcode'. OK, but what runs the microcode? And what runs that? And what runs that? Where does it stop?

Atoms are made into compounds with different electrical properties.

These compounds are made into transistors which act like a switch.

Transistors are made into gates (Nand, And, Not, Or, Nor, Xor, Etc.) These are known as combinatorial circuits, because they combine inputs into an output.

Gates are made into Sequential logic, like Flip Flops, Latches, adders, Etc.

These are made into the basic components you find inside a computer, ALUs, registers etc.

You can find a very good description of all of this at [Computer Architectures - Digital Circuits](http://www.electronicsteacher.com/computer-architectures/digital-circuits/).

(Someone else feel free to improve my answer. It kind of petered out because that's about where my knowledge ends).

Comment: Exactly, but please don't stop at ALU's and Registers... That's all i know. I'd love to know when we actually get to the software part. Can i program 2 4-bit adders? If then, am i supposed to start from Micro-codes? What if i end up describing micro-codes, what then?

Comment: @DimaagNaPakka - Did you check out that link I sent you? It's very informative, and will explain things much better than I can.

Comment: I'm reading it right now. I'll keep you updated if i find what i'm looking for. Thank you so much for the link.

Answer (score 1):

> The hardware that runs the microcode might not be 'code' itself, but it can be 'created' from VHDL code.

Well a "standard" CPU (Intel / AMD etc), is not an FPGA (which would run VHDL / Verilog), but rather is hardware.

So the immediate "level" below microcode is the hardware.

Technically, an Intel (e.g.) cpu *can* be micro programmed, but practically, only if you work for Intel (or have a lot of time on your hands to figure out their encrypted microcode).

So the **software** really starts (for an end user), at the assembler level (ya, you can use a debugger and "poke" hex numbers in, but it's basically the same thing as assembler)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the next step after transistors are logic gates. You can make a simple NOR gate out of two transistors, a NOT gate out of one transistor. Then you combine gates to make basic stuff like adders and counters that you combine to a processor that can run commands. But it's a loooooong way till you connect to it via USB.

As far as programming is concerned, imho the closest thing you can get is FPGA - it's a chip with millions of basic logic gates that can be combined in different ways to get whatever functionality you need, like a full computer.

Comment: In other words, FPGA provides you with usable HDL commands? Does that mean, HDL is lower then micro-code? I always thought of them as unrelated because one aim at hardware and other at software. I see where you are heading with your answer but i actually meant how do you come up with that commands(I mean how do you assign such a code to some ASCII letters)?

Comment: To put it simply, what paves the path to call it a "code" or "instructions" to begin with? Well, i understand they're all bunch of transistors working in a way that they should but what "assigns" that behavior to translate into a language or codes or instructions?

Comment: NOT gates are made with 2 transistors, NOR gates with 4.

Comment: @stevenvh The writer might have confused CMOS with NMOS and PMOS transistors... A NOT gate requires 2 transistors, 1 NMOS and 1 PMOS which is actually one CMOS transistor. Similarly, NOR gate requires 4 (: I prefer if we explain why.

Comment: Speaking of computer architecture there is a Control Unit that reads an instruction and configures ALU for some oparation to perform. So Control Unit performs translation of operation code to some action. It all depends on complexity of your instructions - you can implement them directly in Control Unit, or you may want Microcode Control Unit, that has a small program for every machine instruction composed of primitive actions like "connect register to input of ALU" or "set ALU to perform addition"

Comment: regarding transistor count - i mean, you CAN make a NOR gate out of two transistors, not that it's how it's made nowdays. http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~mssz/CompOrg/Figure1.17-NORcircuit.gif

Comment: @DimaagNa - Well, everything is CMOS now, NMOS has been dead since eons. It's silly to use it as an example.